# Getting Run-time error '4198': Command Failed on Simple Excel VBA command open an exisisting word document

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, ms-word, runtime-error

While running my VBA script, a 4198 error popped out and I couldn't find a way to solve it.

[image]

Any idea ?
The code is used to update the links between a word and excel documents.

```
'code starts here

Sub ChangeAllLinks()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWb As Object
    Dim strOldLink As String
    Dim strNewLink As String
    Dim strWordpath As String
    'Set the old and new links
    strOldLink = "C:\Users\elsaad\OneDrive - NGE\Bureau\old link\test link.xlsm"
    strNewLink = "C:\Users\elsaad\OneDrive - NGE\Bureau\new link\test link.xlsm"
    strWordpath = "C:\Users\elsaad\OneDrive - NGE\Bureau\new link\without MRS.docm"
    'Create a Word application object
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    'Open the Word document
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strWordpath)
    'Create an Excel application object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    'Open the Excel workbook
    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strOldLink)
    
    'Loop through all links in the Word document
    For Each lnk In wdDoc.Hyperlinks
        'Check if the link is to an Excel file
        If InStr(lnk.Address, ".xlsm") > 0 Then
            'Update the link if it matches the old link
            If lnk.Address = strOldLink Then
                lnk.Address = strNewLink
            End If
        End If
    Next lnk
    
    'Loop through all links in the Excel workbook
    For Each lnk In xlWb.LinkSources
        'Update the link if it matches the old link
        If lnk = strOldLink Then
            xlWb.ChangeLink Name:=lnk, NewName:=strNewLink, Type:=xlExcelLinks
        End If
    Next lnk
    
    'Save and close the Word document
    wdDoc.Save
    wdDoc.Close
    
    'Save and close the Excel workbook
    xlWb.Save
    xlWb.Close
    
    'Quit the Excel and Word applications
    xlApp.Quit
    wdApp.Quit
    
    'Clean up
    Set xlWb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried searching for an answer but none were matching my case. And the problem is that all the soultions that I found were for other applications.

Comment: Where in the code does the error occur? Have you debugged/stepped through your code?

Comment: Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strWordpath)

Comment: What is the exact error message? 4198 error comes with lot of messages. For example `Microsoft Word Error 4198 Software Error.` or 
`Microsoft Word Error 4198 can't be found.` or 
`Sorry, we can't find Microsoft Word Error 4198.` etc etc... It would be great of you can add a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: I added the screenshot at the beginning of the post.

Comment: The exact error is : Run-time error '4198' Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Does "without MRS.docm" contain any code which might run when the file is opened?

Comment: No @TimWilliams