# Getting Run-time error '4198': Command Failed on Simple Excel VBA command open an exisiting Word document

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, ms-word, hyperlink

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm201.png)While running my VBA script, a 4198 error popped out and I couldn't find a way to solve it.

```
'code starts here

Sub ChangeAllLinks()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWb As Object
    Dim strOldLink As String
    Dim strNewLink As String
    Dim strWordpath As String
    'Set the old and new links
    strOldLink = "C:\Users\elsaad\OneDrive - NGE\Bureau\old link\test link.xlsm"
    strNewLink = "C:\Users\elsaad\OneDrive - NGE\Bureau\new link\test link.xlsm"
    strWordpath = "C:\Users\elsaad\OneDrive - NGE\Bureau\new link\without MRS.docm"
    'Create a Word application object
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    'Open the Word document -> **error in the following line **
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strWordpath) 
    'Create an Excel application object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    'Open the Excel workbook
    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strOldLink)
    
    'Loop through all links in the Word document
    For Each lnk In wdDoc.Hyperlinks
        'Check if the link is to an Excel file
        If InStr(lnk.Address, ".xlsm") > 0 Then
            'Update the link if it matches the old link
            If lnk.Address = strOldLink Then
                lnk.Address = strNewLink
            End If
        End If
    Next lnk
    
    'Loop through all links in the Excel workbook
    For Each lnk In xlWb.LinkSources
        'Update the link if it matches the old link
        If lnk = strOldLink Then
            xlWb.ChangeLink Name:=lnk, NewName:=strNewLink, Type:=xlExcelLinks
        End If
    Next lnk
    
    'Save and close the Word document
    wdDoc.Save
    wdDoc.Close
    
    'Save and close the Excel workbook
    xlWb.Save
    xlWb.Close
    
    'Quit the Excel and Word applications
    xlApp.Quit
    wdApp.Quit
    
    'Clean up
    Set xlWb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
`
```

I tried searching for an answer but none were matching my case. And the problem is that all the soultions that I found were for other applications.

Comment: This question looks familiar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75555957/getting-run-time-error-4198-command-failed-on-simple-excel-vba-command-open-a

Comment: What line does arise the error?

Comment: Have you tried running the code under the debugger attached? What lie of code throws an exception/error at runtime?

Comment: Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strWordpath)  @EugeneAstafiev

Comment: Make sure the file exists on the disk and can be opened at least manually.

Comment: Yes I checked it and it exists, the file locations are good @EugeneAstafiev

Comment: Try to use any file path without whitespaces and see whether it works correctly in that case.